# Call Method every x seconds

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

I'm using Scala and the Playframework and I'm trying to get a method executed every 20 seconds.

The code I use is:

```
val system = akka.actor.ActorSystem("system")
system.scheduler.schedule(0 seconds, 30 seconds)(worker())
```

This seems to work, but after about 20 minutes it just stops calling the worker method. What is the problem?

Comment: No, it doesn't throw any exception

Comment: Which version of Play Framework you're using?

Comment: What does worker do? Does is do some long running and blocking computation?